# Binding a value to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, bind

Lets say I have this function:

```
function toy(input) {
    return input + 1;
}
```

I want to essentially generate a function that will print 4 by binding 3 to input. So that I could call something like fn() and it will print 4.

So I tried doing:

```
var fn = toy.bind(3);
```

Then when I executed fn(), I'm not getting 4.

Do I need to use 'this' in order to make this work/Is there a way to do this without bind?

Comment: `bind` doesn't do what you think it does!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument passed to `.bind()` is used as the `this` in the called function. The first argument to be pass to the called function is the ***second*** parameter passed to `.bind()`. You *can* use a meaningful `this` binding if there is one, or just use `null` if the function ignores `this`:

```
var fn = toy.bind(null, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of `bind` is the context of `this` so you need to pass 3 as the 2nd argument:

```
var fn = toy.bind(this, 3);
```

Then it will work :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do this without `bind`?

Yes:

```
var fn = function() { return toy(3); };
```

Or if you want to pass `fn`'s `this` along:

```
var fn = function() { return toy.call(this, 3); };
```